# Could there be a meta CW or curated list of other venues for OT questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, community-wiki

I think I'm probably inviting the *Paradox Police* here, but...

I wanted to post a URL to an author site and ask for a design/UX critique. A little poking around and I found a principle of "Don't ask for website critiques; besides a potential spam smell, critique questions are subjective and therefore off-topic."

The natural question that leaves me with is, "The website critique I want is not appropriate anywhere under the SE umbrella; where might I go instead?" I have on a piecemeal basis found other good venues, i.e. Tom's for computer hardware / product recommendations.

Perhaps (donning asbestos) there could be one exception, a curated community wiki for good places to go to a question that is off-topic under the entire SE umbrella. It is my opinion that there are some good, valuable questions that fall off-topic at times; I know it is not helpful to say "XYZ is a valuable question; if it's valuable we should change principles of inclusion," but it might be helpful, instead of saying "Your potentially valuable question is off-topic [note that I am not making that claim necessarily for my intended request for a website critique]; here are some other forums listed in the CW that would be more appropriate."

Ok, waiting to get arrested by the Paradox Police...

Comment: There was a list for this, but it was deleted by a moderator. The deleted answer is contained in this question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254567/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-dont-fit-or-are-off-topic-for-stack-overflow but you need 10k rep to view it.

Comment: I've taken the list, removed all the Stack Exchange sites since you know how to find those, and posted it below as an answer.  It's wiki so feel free to edit it if you find other useful Q&A sites or forums where questions rejected by Stack Exchange may be asked.

Answer (score 5):

The very creation and curation of such a list would be subjective. What sites are better? Why did site A deserve mention or deserve being mentioned first over site B?

As such, the list would be subject to edit wars, and attract spammers that want to see their current client's site listed, or listed higher, or whatever. And spammers don't limit themselves to links that are on topic either, anything for more visibility and page rank!

There is a reason Stack Exchange avoids lists and recommendations, and a curated list of sites to take your off-topic post to is subject to the same limitations and problems.

Instead, I think it is better to stick to a more non-committal statement: *take open-ended discussions to another site, it is off-topic here*. And we leave it at that.

Comment: When we had a list we didn't experience ***any*** of those problems.  It was just fine. I'm not sure why the list was deleted, other than NIH syndrome.

Comment: @AdamDavis: what list was that?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254568/2915

Comment: I am aware; hence my remark about the Paradox Police, whom you represent. But a list of non-SE sites for out-of-scope questions would reduce the OT traffic here, and be useful even if ironic.

Comment: I for one think that this is a very important question that many people would benefit from having the answer to. Regarding lists - many other lists exists in the StackOverflow universe, including book recommendations for c++ programmers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of sites that aren't connected to Stack Exchange where you might find help that is not permitted on Stack Exchange sites:

#### IT

- [TechRepublic](http://techrepublic.com)
- [Microsoft TechNet Forums](http://forums.technet.microsoft.com/)

#### Networking

- [DevShed Network forum](http://forums.devshed.com/networking-help-109/)

#### Computer hardware

- [Ars Technica OpenForum](http://arstechnica.com/civis/)
- [Tom's Hardware Forums](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/)

#### Computer software

- [Anandtech Forum](http://forums.anandtech.com/)

#### Microsoft based operating systems

- [NT, Win2K, & XP Technical Mojo](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewforum.php?f=17)
- [Microsoft OS & Software Colloquium](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewforum.php?f=15)

#### *nix based operating systems

(Users and administrators, not programmers)

- [Linux Forums](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/)
- [Linux Kung Fu](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewforum.php?f=16)

#### Web Hosting/CMS/SEO

- [SitePoint forums](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums)
- [Web Hosting Talk](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/)

#### Math and science

- [PlanetMath](http://planetmath.org/)
- [Physics Forums](http://www.physicsforums.com/)

#### Games

- [Magic: The Gathering](http://draw3cards.com/)

#### IDEs

- [Eclipse](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/itanswers/tag/eclipse-ide/)
- [Atlassian](https://answers.atlassian.com/)
- [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/support)

#### Other/General

- [Yahoo! Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/)
- [Google Search](http://www.google.com)
- [AskMeFi](http://ask.metafilter.com/)
- [Quora](https://www.quora.com/)

Comment: One alternative to this solution is to link to a place were this question is allowed. Without this question and answer, this is going to keep go unanswered, and someone will ask the question again.